# iPad bookmarklet not popping up

Tags: javascript, ipad, bookmarklet

I have a js bookmarklet which works perfectly on all browsers. It spawns a pop up window when clicked. Apart from the iPad - it spawns a new tab as opposed to a pop up

NOTE: I have turned OFF the Block Pop-ups feature in Safari

This is the bookmarklet code I use:

```
javascript:(function(){window.open('http://****.com/pages/bm/add.html?
page_title='+document.title+'&rl='+encodeURIComponent(window.location.href),
'bookmarklet','left=100,top=100,width=610,height=700,personalbar=0,toolbar=0
,scrollbars=1,resizable=1')})()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clarification to the previous two answers, it's possible, but you can't rely on that behaviour because it's a user preference:

> By default, Safari on iOS blocks pop-up windows. However, it is a
>   preference that the user can change. To change the Safari settings,
>   tap Settings followed by Safari. The Block Pop-ups setting appears in
>   the Security section.
>   From: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html

This is a view source bookmarklet that pops open a new window.  Try this one out to see if it works:

```
javascript:(function()%7Bvar%20a=window.open(%22about:blank%22).document;a.write(%22%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%3Chtml%3E%3Chead%3E%3Ctitle%3ESource%20of%20%22+location.href+'%3C/title%3E%3Cmeta%20name=%22viewport%22%20content=%22width=device-width%22%20/%3E%3C/head%3E%3Cbody%3E%3C/body%3E%3C/html%3E');a.close();var%20b=a.body.appendChild(a.createElement(%22pre%22));b.style.overflow=%22auto%22;b.style.whiteSpace=%22pre-wrap%22;b.appendChild(a.createTextNode(document.documentElement.innerHTML))%7D)();
```

Comment: Thanks - I did know this and should have added that i turned off the block pop ups on the iPad - why someone decided this was not a valid question is beyond me! I will amend the question

Comment: What happens if you just do a normal window.open from a plain html file? Sorry I don't have my iPad on me to test.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I added an example of a view source bookmarklet, let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

iOS doesn't do popups, just tabs. For the record, Android does tabs.

Answer (score 1):

iOS doesn't do windows, of any kind.